# Import file from website using process indiciator

Tags: import, web-access

Would it be possible to have some sort of progress indicator for downloading files?

For example if we would like to import:
`Import["http://lieanalysis.com/exampledata/os.mx"]`

It would take a while, it would be nice if you have some sort of progress indicator (like mathematica uses for `ExampleData`)

Comment: @Kuba can't believe i've missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`URLSaveAsynchronous`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/URLSaveAsynchronous.html) to download, then `Import` the downloaded file. There's an example in the documentation about progress bars.

Be aware that I experienced some problems with this function. In version 11 sometimes it would get stuck after the download has finished.  See the discussion:

- http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/972349

Comment: Thanks for your answer, somehow I must have overlooked this function. Will accept you answer when I'm allowed :)

Comment: @FrankMartin Well, there's URLSave, URLFetch, URLFetchAsynchronous, URLSubmit, URLDonwload, URLRead, Import, HTTPRequest and so on and so on.  Some are deprecated and won't show up in auto-completion. Not so easy to find the right one. Once again be careful because this kept hanging for me on Windows when wrapped in WaitAsynchronousTask.

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning that `"Content-Length"` header has to be present for progress indicator to show progress correctly. It usually is there but happened to me that it wasn't.